# How should I extend MvxTrace in mvvmcross?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I've implemented a specific implementation of IMvxTrace that logs to a file as well as the console, and it's working just fine.  But what I'd like to do now is add a new method that I can use to log Exceptions, so I'd like to add a method signature to the interface.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
public interface IMvxTraceExt : IMvxTrace
{
    void LogException(Exception ex);
}
```

And just creating an object that implements that, but of course when I finally make the object and return it in `CreateDebugTrace`, it looses the extended interface definition:

```
protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
{
    return new DebugTrace();
}
```

It's not really surprising... Overall the objective would be to have it so that I could do the following in code:

```
MvxTrace.TaggedError("Setup", "registering unhandled exception logging");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => {        
    var trace = MvxTrace.Instance as IMvxTraceExt;
    trace.LogException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
};
```

Above, 'trace' becomes null with the cast -- so the cast isn't doing what I was thinking it might.  Really, my preference would be able to just hit the method directly off of MvxTrace like so:

```
MvxTrace.TaggedError("Setup", "registering unhandled exception logging");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => {        
    MvxTrace.LogException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
};
```

But that implies that MvxTrace itself needs to be a type that implements the extended mvxtrace interface, and I don't see a way of doing that other than to tweak the source itself which I'm not really wanting to do.

Side note: The reason I want LogException in the same object that implements the other trace functions is because I've got code that manages appending to a log file in there and it seems natural to extend it in this way.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MvxTrace` itself is just a set of static helper methods to make calls to the actual `IMvxTrace` implementation less verbose and as an optimisation - `MvxTrace` acts as a singleton in order to avoid looking up `IMvxTrace` as a Service for every single trace call.

Because the helpers are `static` then it's not going to be easy to override that class and change the behaviour.

For your requirements, you could declare an additional `TraceEx` static class to help:

```
public class MyTrace
{
   private static IMvxTraceExt _traceExt;

   private static IMvxTraceExt TraceExt
   {
      get { return _traceExt ?? _traceExt = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTrace>() as IMvxTraceExt; }
   }

   public static void LogException(Exception exc)
   {
       TraceExt.LogException(exc):
   }
}
```

This may seem like a hassle... but it only has to be done once - and I often add an application specific static trace class anyway - as it helps ensure consistency of trace `Tag` logging - e.g. see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/Trace.cs